# Internal server error in heroku after deploying django project

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have deployed a project in heroku. The deployment was successful but now I am getting interal server error. After going through the logs i got this

```
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513605+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513607+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513608+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513608+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513608+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513611+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513612+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513613+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513613+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513613+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513613+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513613+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513614+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513615+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response or self.get_response(request)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513615+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513616+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 152, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513616+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 611, in resolve_error_handler
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513617+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513617+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513617+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513618+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513618+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513618+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513620+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513622+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513622+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513623+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513624+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513624+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513624+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513624+00:00 app[web.1]: self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513625+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513625+00:00 app[web.1]: respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513625+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513625+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.get_response(request)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513625+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513626+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513626+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513626+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513629+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513629+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513629+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 152, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513629+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513630+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 611, in resolve_error_handler
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513630+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513630+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513630+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513631+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513631+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513631+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513631+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513631+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513633+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513633+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513633+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513633+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513633+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513634+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513634+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513634+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513634+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513635+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T12:31:11.513709+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.6.216 - - [29/Oct/2021:12:31:11 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
2021-10-29T12:31:11.514428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rickritankar.herokuapp.com request_id=183f16cb-228a-456d-aa62-6d4dd588667d fwd="47.29.48.110" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=244 protocol=https

C:\Users\rickb\Desktop>heroku logs --app rickritankar
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101671+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101671+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101672+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101672+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101672+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101672+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101673+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101673+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101673+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101674+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101674+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101674+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101677+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101678+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101678+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101678+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101679+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101679+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101679+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101679+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101680+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101680+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101680+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101681+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101681+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101681+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response or self.get_response(request)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101681+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101682+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101682+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101682+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101682+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 152, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101688+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101688+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 611, in resolve_error_handler
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101689+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101689+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101689+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101690+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101690+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101690+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101690+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101691+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101692+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101692+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101692+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101692+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101693+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101693+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101693+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101693+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101694+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101694+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101694+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101694+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101695+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101695+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101696+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101696+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101697+00:00 app[web.1]: self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101697+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 179, in handle_request
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101697+00:00 app[web.1]: respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101697+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101698+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.get_response(request)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101698+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101698+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101698+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101698+00:00 app[web.1]: response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101701+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101701+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101702+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 152, in handle_uncaught_exception
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101702+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101702+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 611, in resolve_error_handler
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101703+00:00 app[web.1]: callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101703+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101703+00:00 app[web.1]: res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101704+00:00 app[web.1]: return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101705+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/jgs/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101707+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('home.urls')),
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101708+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101708+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101708+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101708+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101709+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101709+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-29T14:08:59.101709+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home.urls'
2021-10-29T14:08:59.102099+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.6.216 - - [29/Oct/2021:14:08:59 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
2021-10-29T14:08:59.103324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rickritankar.herokuapp.com request_id=8a1e6bf3-206a-4318-9d32-d196ab34261e fwd="103.38.89.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=244 protocol=https
```

Here it says cannot import home.urls, but since it is an app this routed to the base project with the include tag like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include ,re_path 
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),

    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

this code ran on localhost just fine but now I am getting this error.

Please suggest me whats should I do.

Comment: Can you show us a structure of the project directory ? It will help a lot

Comment: Thank you soo much for responding, but the problem was with the drag and drop optikn in GitHub. It was not loading all the files. Later I pushed it from the cli and now everi is working fine.